# Angular : Unable to pass API url in SignalR HubConnection

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I have developed a project in Angular6. There is a requirement to develop section for live chat. For that I am using SignalR in my asp.net core Web Apiproject. Now I want to use this Web Api reference in my Angular project.

I am using [this](https://medium.com/@rukshandangalla/how-to-notify-your-angular-5-app-using-signalr-5e5aea2030b2) link.

But while providing the Web Api url in App.Component.ts, I am getting below error :

> Constructor of class 'HubConnection' is private and only accessible
>   within the class declaration.

**App Component.ts :**

```
import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Message } from 'primeng/api';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public _hubConnection: HubConnection;
  msgs: Message[] = [];
  constructor() {   
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:1874/notify'); // getting error on this line.
```

**Edit** : tried below code :-

Modified App.Component.ts :

```
import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Message } from 'primeng/api';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public _hubConnection: HubConnection;
  msgs: Message[] = [];
  constructor() {   
  }
  ngOnInit() {       
    this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
          .withUrl('http://localhost:1874/notify')
          .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
          .build();
```

**Error :**

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:1874/notify/negotiate: Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which
>   must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
>   Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 5):

They changed the constructors for SignalR Client `HubConnection` to no longer allow you to pass the route in the client constructor and made the `HubConnection` constructor private to enforce the change. Instead, you need to use the `HubConnectionBuilder` as follows:

`new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/YOURROUTEHERE").build();`

You will want to import the HubConnectionBuilder in your header as follows:

`import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';`

In case it helps, I also just posted an update to my RxSignalR samples for @aspnet/signalr 1.0.2, RxJs 5.5.6 and Angular 6. Check out the [ReactiveChat component](https://github.com/jwooley/SignalrRxSamples/blob/master/SignalrAngular6/ClientApp/src/app/reactiveChat/reactiveChat.component.ts) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

In your server code, are you using CORS?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
               .AllowCredentials();
    }));

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        // your routes
    });

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 private hubConnection: signalr.HubConnection;    
 message: string;
 ngOnInit() {
    this.hubConnection = new signalr.HubConnection('');

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection started!');
        this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (message) => { 
          alert(message);
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

  }
```

Comment: but now package been renamed to import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr';

Comment: getting error "can not find namespace signalr", if I change it to signalR then getting error "constructor of the class HubConnection is private and only accesible within class declration"

Comment: check this https://github.com/bursauxa/magoria/blob/5574e3982b78486e3f681b61cbfed89381bb0b72/client/src/services/LobbyService.ts

Comment: did that help  ?

Comment: The beta clients allowed you to pass the route in the HubConnection constructor. The release version now requires you to use a HubConnectionBuilder instead.