# I am not hitting my api route in backend controller from angular frontend. What am I doing incorrect?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular, controller

I am getting this error zone.js:3243 POST https://localhost:44424/api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Here is my service api call

```
  updateMessage(message: any) {
    console.log("at service")
    console.log(message)
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit', message)
  }
```

When I console.log message I receive this.

```
Object
departments: 4
noteBody: "asdf"
weeks: SLGTime {year: 2020, week: 12, quarter: 1, weekEnding: "2020-01-18T00:00:00", lyweekEnding: "2019-01-19T00:00:00"}
__proto__: Object
```

So I know I am sending information to the .net controller in the back end.  Here is my controller method.  Is this possibly not set up to receive the angular info correctly?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit")]
public void Edit([FromBody]object item)
{

    _SLGContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _SLGContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

More info that may be useful.  Here is the name of my namespace and Route

```
namespace mocHub2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SlgCorpNotesController : Controller
```

This is my formgroup info that i'm sending.

```
this.optionsForm = new FormGroup({
  departments: new FormControl(),
  weeks: new FormControl(),
  noteBody: new FormControl()
})
```

I think what it is, is Im not naming something correctly.  Sorry this is my first .net/angular project.  Usually Im just on razor views and .net mvc!

Comment: Try to see whether your code `this.baseUrl + 'api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit'` creates a correct URL. It can be seen what url is used to make API call in network tab of your browser

Comment: Do you have CORS configured to allow an HTTP OPTIONS verb?

Comment: I will check that StepUp and Jonathon,  Im sure I do have Cors, I was able to make api calls for other methods

Comment: still no luck :( I created a model for the object being sent and received. It is an object with one int, one datetime, and one string. This should be easy right? I am able to do a get post easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an object manually. newMessage.

I also had to put HttpHeaders

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')

let options = { headers: headers };
```

Here is the method updated.

```
updateMessage(message: any) {
    console.log("at service")
    console.log(message)
    //var newMessage = new CorpNotes(message['departments'], message['noteBody'], message['weeks'].weekEnding)
    //console.log(newMessage)
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(newMessage))
    var newMessage = {
      "Departments": message["departments"],
      "Note": message["noteBody"],
      "WeekEnding": message["weeks"].weekEnding
    }
    console.log(newMessage)
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')

    let options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit',newMessage, options);
    //return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit', JSON.stringify(newMessage))


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending it as a JSON,

```
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit', JSON.stringify(message));
```

and your method body should have the object of the type

```
public void Edit([FromBody]TypeOfObject item)
```

Comment: It still gives me the error zone.js:3243 POST https://localhost:44424/api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279989/unable-to-post-values-from-angular-service-to-web-api-in-asp-net-core-angular

Comment: still no luck :(  I created a model for the object being sent and received.  It is an object with one int, one datetime, and one string.  This should be easy right?  I am able to do a get post easy!